# Change the iframe file name - asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have a iframe like

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="/content/#@(fileUrl)" style="width: 100%; height:100%" frameborder="0" allow="fullscreen"></iframe>
```

fileUrl comes as a GuId and I don't want to download the file named as a GuId. I want to change it with a parameter I send in .cshtml file.